Unable to upgrade PIP or install modules in Python 3.9
I'm trying to install PyPDF2 into a work laptop, and unfortunately, I get the following errors in the command prompt:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pypdf2/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyPDF2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyPDF2

The warning also repeats five times total.
I tried to use pip show to see if PyPDF2 was in my pip, and of course, it wasn't.
I tried upgrading pip using
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

leading to the exact same warning I experienced before and pip aparently already being updated?
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python39-64\lib\site-packages (21.2.4)    
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

This is a pretty new work laptop, and this is my first time using python with it. It's worth mentioning that I have two versions installed on the laptop, 3.9 and 2.7. I can't delete 2.7 as I need admin permission, but worst case I could just do that. Just looking for some troubleshooting tips and/or ideas for these warnings I keep getting.

Can you install another arbitrary package with PIP? This is just to check this is not a networking issue (e.g., Internet connectivity, firewall, proxy, etc.)
If this not PIP-related, maybe this because your python version is too old (even if PyPDF2 claims it supports python3.9, see here). Indeed, I did not face the problem under Debian (using python3.12):
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-venv
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install PyPDF2

Results of the last command:
Collecting PyPDF2
  Downloading pypdf2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Downloading pypdf2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyPDF2
Successfully installed PyPDF2-3.0.1


The console outputs that you've provided suggest that your connection is being interrupted when pip tried to reach the PyPI servers.
Assuming you are using Windows.
Start by opening cmd by doing windows_key + r and open cmd
Type python -V or python3 -V to get the version of python that is in your PATH environment variable.
PyPDF2 requires Python 3.6.15 or higher.
Then download the .whl file PyPDF2 from PyPi under Built Distribution and place the .whl file in a directory.
For example:

C:\Users\{your_user}\Desktop\temp

Re-open cmd and navigate to the directory where you saved the .whl file.
Type the following command to install PyPDF2 from the .whl file.
python -m pip install {filename.whl}

This will also indicate if the issue comes from the connection to PyPi or if it's pip related.
If it doesn't work then it's probably a pip/Python version or path issue.
Good luck

Thanks for the answers and help, it is all truly appreciated.
I had to go to my company's it desk and get a special line to allow the corporate host to install PyPDF2. That is all I needed.
If anyone ever encounters this, keep my answer in mind.

This is not a chat, every post here should be an answer to the problem
if you want to chat, use the "reply" feature
